# Facebook SSO and request iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I am trying to post a wall message to the current user. Before I am doing the request I am validating the session and authorizing if it isn't. I left out some of the declarations and the initializing of the variables since to clarify. The problem is that the code shown here is executed before the fbDidLogin-delegate method is executed. So it seems like the Facebook object doesn't have the valid access token before it is requesting. I have made a singleton. Next time I run the program it works.

Delegate

```
- (void)fbDidLogin 
{
    NSLog(@"DEBUG: DID LOG IN");

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Viewcontroller

```
Facebook *facebook = [SocialMedia sharedFacebookAuthorized];

        NSString *name = nil;
        NSString *message = nil;
        NSString *picture = nil;

        if (self.didPassTest) {
            // Code
        } else {
            // Code
        }

        NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       name, @"name",
                                       message, @"message",
                                       picture, @"picture",
                                       description, @"description",
                                       link, @"link",
                                       caption, @"caption", nil];

        [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

SharedFacebook..function

```
+ (Facebook *)sharedFacebookAuthorized 
{
    [self sharedFacebook];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", @"read_stream", @"publish_stream", nil] retain];

    NSLog(@"START?");

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [facebook authorize:permissions];
        NSLog(@"INSIDE?");
    }

    NSLog(@"CONTINUE?");    
    return facebook;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an asynchronous task.  You have to wait for the authorize asynchronous call to complete before requesting anything from the graph API.  See my response to a similar question here: [How to react to asynchronous events (login)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830976/how-to-react-to-asynchronous-events-login/6831138#6831138)

Comment: dtuckernet: Thank you for you reply, you understood my question. But how do I use these blocks? I have never used one before.

Comment: dtuckernet: And are there no other way? I need to have this working on > 3.2, and blocks was added in iOS 4.

Comment: You can define your own delegates for this.  This would be the same way the Facebook SDK uses delegates.